# drag and drop in android 2.1

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I believe the drag and drop functionality is not available until 3.0, right? So how can I create a drag and drop in lower version, I'm currently working on 2.1..

I've seen a [tutorial](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html), but the drag and drop is a bit unrealistic since the imageview is a bit off the finger. Any other suggestions? thanks

Comment: If you want drag and drop in 2.1 you'll have to write it yourself. It's quite realistic though.

Comment: I'm trying to write one, but I'm stuck with moving the imageview in the framelayout, how do I do this?

Comment: How about using a surfaceview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you wrap your current layout in a FrameLayout and add a transparent AbsoluteLayout to which you could relocate the view to be dragged? Dropping would be a bit of a challenge...

Maybe view the source to see how they do it in 3.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library for drag & drop.
http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/